# Is is possible to have rounded background of selected Bottom Navigation item?

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

So this is what I am trying to achieve (corners are rounded): [image: round corners of selected item]

And here is where I'm stuck at (corners are not rounded): [image: corners not rounded]

Main activity xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    style="@style/CustomBottomNavigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
    app:itemBackground="@color/bottom_navigation_bar_background_color"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_bar_content_color"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_bar_content_color"/>
```

color/bottom_navigation_background_color.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/background_selected" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/background" />
</selector>
```

color/bottom_navigation_content_color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/text_active" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/text_inactive" />
</selector>
```

Comment: If you don't want to deal with trying to customize it, you can try to create a custom bottom bar and use CardViews + Ripple effect to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're trying to use color instead of drawable.

In the drawable folder create an xml called background_menu_item.xml, with content:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/nav_bar_colors_bg" />
    <corners android:radius="120dp" />
</shape>
```

In the color folder create another XML called nav_bar_colors_bg.xml, with content like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/navBarActiveIconColor" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/navBarInactiveIconColor" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Then in the xml where you have the bottom navigation view add:

```
app:itemBackground="@drawable/background_menu_item"
```

Also if you'd like to change the icon color as well then add:

```
app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_bar_colors"
```

and create a nav_bar_colors.xml in the drawable folder with content like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/navBarInactiveIconColor" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/navBarActiveIconColor" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Also make sure that the android:background is your inactive color to align with material design:

```
android:background="@color/navBarActiveIconColor"
```

Note: namings could be better I know + SO formed my reply incorrectly and due to lack of time I rather deleted it, but now after formatting I cannot undelete it so I'm posting it again.